# communicating between two components with single call

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am stuck in a basic scenario in which I have a component (`component1`) on which when I perform a certain operation I want to get some data from another component (to be precise I am sending some content from (`component2`).

[image]

For now, I am doing it using two subjects which are shared via a common service, first I am broadcasting some data from component1 which is subscribed in `component2`, upon that data some action is performed and componet2 send me the response for which I made a subscription in `component1`. For details Kindly refer above snapshot, as specified above both components are not related to each other.

What I wanted to achieve is to have a **single call** which when I perform an action in `component1` will call `component2` and I'll get the response, kindly provide some suggestions and direction to look into.

Requested code

**component1.ts**

```
click(data) {
  subject1.next(data);
  subject2.subscribe(s => {
    alert(s);
  });
}
```

**component2.ts**

```
subject1.subscribe(s => {
  subject2.next(s+10);
});
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code please

Comment: have already shared in the snapshot, what else you require kindly specify

Comment: i think this is a good solution. There are some other ways you could do it, like register your component in the service and then access a public method from the component, but I don't think it's as good

Comment: @ShamPooSham true that registering the component wouldn't be feasible

Comment: Do you know what InjectionToken are and how to use them? They allow you to decouple dependencies very easily. If this is something that you are intereested in I can post an answer/explanation?

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanStellwag after your comment I referred to the InjectionToken, it will decouple the dependencies but I guess to resolve my problem using injectionToken I can create an object of my component2 and inject it inside component1 and use it on every action, but here I can't do so. As you can see both the components are on a different project/library, component1 is a part of library where component2 is the consumer of that library, if it is vice-versa I may give it a try

Comment: I agree with @JonathanStellwag I think DI may be super useful here

Answer (score 1):

Both of your components are available from `app.component.ts` aren't they?? (or any other parent component containing both of them)

The following approach is the more natural way to cover your use case, the way you are currently using services looks like an antipattern to me.

Use [EventEmitter's](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter):

**component1.ts**

```js
@Output()
public dataReady = new EventEmitter<any>();
click(data) {
  dataReady.emit(data);
}
finalData(data) {
  console.log('Data has been processed by component2, result:', data);
}
```

**component2.ts**

```js
@Output()
public dataProcessed = new EventEmitter<any>();
processData(data) {
  // Do whatever you do in component 2 with data: s + 10?
  dataProcessed.emit(data);
}
```

At component's container:

```html
<app-component1 #component1 (dataReady)="component2.processData($event)"></app-component1>
<app-component2 #component2 (dataProcessed)="component1.finalData($event)"></app-component2>
```

However, if both of your components are "too far" that you can't call each other events, I think the right approach would be to process data inside your service and leave alone your component2 (by moving the "processData" code from component2 to your service)

Answer (score -1):

I think you may just write your own observable-like thing:

```js
class Service {
   subscription;

   consumerSubscribe(subscription) {
       this.subscription = subscription;
   }

   consumerUnsubscribe() {
       this.subscription = null;
   }

   librarySubscription() {
       return subscription();
   }
}
```

component1:

```js
click(data) {
    this.service.librarySubscription(data).subscribe(s => alert(s));
}
```

component2:

```js
this.service.consumerSubscribe(s => of(s + 10)) // lets allow consumer use async method -- you may use sync ofc.
this.service.consumerUnsubscribe(); // consumer will need to unsub, but that is true for normal observable as well
```

P.S.: You can do pretty same using e.g. `Subject` and its private fields and btw I feel something wrong here but without knowledge of initial problem it is hard to say something more...

Comment: Pretty decent approach, let me give it a try

Comment: @Petr Averyanov Maybe in the method `librarySubscription() {return subscription();}` there is a typo. Shouldn't it be `librarySubscription(data) {return this.subscription(data);}`?